# Visual Studio 2017 project can't run/debug in Parallels Desktop on Mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I really need your help. I'm new to learn C#. I've followed each steps of *Head First C#*. In the book, the Visual Studio version is 2012, and the project type it tells me to create is Blank App (XAML) Visual C#, which I can't find in my Visual Studio 2017, so I choose the type described below.

**About my computer/system:**

Software: Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

The project type is: Blank App (Universal Windows) Visual C#.

Computer: Using [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) to run Windows10 on Mac OSX.

The Parallels Desktop, which is a virtual machine software used for running Windows 10 on my Mac. I create my project in this virtual machine, and after I finished the project follow the steps from book, there is no error in editor. But after I pressed the green-play-button, I got some error I posted below.

[image: error]

Comment: Are you trying to make a game for a phone? that is the type of project you selected. "Head First C#" is likely going to only teach you how to make desktop applications instead of phone applications.

Comment: Don't use comments to just say thanks, also you did not answer my question. Are you trying to make a game for a phone?

Comment: It's a Windows Store App. @ScottChamberlain

Comment: You set the build process to target an actual device but no such device is connected to your VM. Either forward your USB device via Parallels to Windows, or use an emulator. Explained in more detail here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441483.aspx)

Comment: If you want to run the app within Windows, you need to set "Target Device" to Local Machine. Explained here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632391.aspx)

Comment: Nothing has changed there between 2015 and 2017. Also, the error message box is exactly telling you what to do. All I can do is copy this text here as instruction. Just read the error message and follow the steps it provides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Check your project is stored in the C:\ drive of Windows10 running in the Parallels Desktop.
2. If you can't find where you store your project:

   1. Back to your Mac OSX > Finder > iCloud Drive > Documents > Visual Studio 2017 > Projects > **Check that whether your project is stored in here, if it does, I will solve your problem.**
   2. If your project is already stored in the C:\ of Windows10 in Parallels Desktop, go search other solution, I can't solve your problem, sorry.
3. > You stored your project in the wrong place.
4. > Don't copy and paste your project directly to Windows10 in the Parallels Desktop.
5. Create the project again. Yes, create it again... But this time, make sure your project is stored in the C:\ in the Parallels Desktop(I mean that the location of your project start with C:\ ).

---

Explain about the error message in the picture:

First I want to say, I'm new to Visual Studio 2017, and I don't know why the language displayed in the Output contains Chinese, I've already changed it to English in the environment settings. Sorry about that if you can't read Chinese.

But what it means in English is :

> Windows can't deploy/debug your project because your project is stored in the file system of type PrlSF.

Since the default path of my project is:

> In Windows on Parallels Desktop > iCloud on 'Mac'(X:) > Documents > Visual Studio 2017 > ...

If you right click the **iCloud on 'Mac'(X:)**, you will find that it is of type **PrlSF**. Yes, as the error message shown, you've stored your project in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following solution in the Parallels forum:
https://forum.parallels.com/threads/prlsf-permissions-issue-when-developing-an-uwp-app-in-visual-studio.342549/

So the credit goes to the user JakubZ in the forum:

> For further reference, the steps to resolve this issue are as follows:
>
> 1. Unload the UWP project (R-click on project and then select "Unload Project"
> 2. Edit the project file in VS (R-click on unloaded project and then select "Edit ...")
> 3. Find an XML entry for the OutputPath. For instance the entry for OutputPath when building for Debug|x86 should look like
>      bin/x86/Debug. Notice that the entry contains
>      relative path.
> 4. Edit the path to an absolute path on one of VMs drives. For instance, to set the path to the %TEMP%\UWPBuilds\x86\Debug directory
>      for the user write $(TEMP)\Debug
> 5. Close the project file
> 6. Reload the project (R-click on unloaded project and then select "Reload Project").

As an addition: As I had multiple run configurations, I also had multiple OutputPath entries. I had to change all of them accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure next to green button "`Debug`" mode is selected and NOT "`Release`"?
Probably you are trying to deploy application instead od running it in `Visual studio - Debug` mode..